Incorrect backlight code in VS code for vue project
enter image description here
If there is a lot of when in the tag attribute, then the display of code highlighting breaks
I don’t know what settings in the editor affect this or what it’s called correctly
Nothing, i dont know who use

give me more info. send a screenshot

screen in https://i.sstatic.net/QDsKUYnZ.png

Clarification - this happens when there is an array inside the attribute

there is no problem there. it indent the code properly to be more readable

The topic is that the color of all code becomes the same - blue
